# How to refresh google drive data source - Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a question regarding refreshing google big query table where the data source is google drive.

Imagine, you have CSV file on google drive and every day someone updates for you.
1. The filename is not changing
2. location URI is same

How can I refresh my big query table by using this google drive file?

Could you please guide me or send me related links?

Thanks

Comment: Would suggest you start with a thorough read of the official documentation on loading data into BigQuery as this will introduce you to several approaches which could be used to do this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data

Comment: You can also directly query the data in google drive provided that the performance is OK for you: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive

Answer (score 0):

From the BigQuery [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data):

> Loading data into BigQuery from Google Drive is not currently
>   supported, but you can query data in Google Drive using an [external
>   table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive).

The link above provides instructions on how to create an external table that references your stored-in-Drive data source. Considering that you want to be querying data from a Google Drive file which you will be updating in Drive, this is the solution you are looking for (in contrast to downloading your csv locally and then loading it into BQ, in which case you would then have to be updating directly in BQ).